# missing BTC - on chain but not in my personnel wallet

Tags: blockchain

Missing Bitcoins BTC

On the 25th Oct 2023 I bought some BTC from the company I always use Bitttylicious the wallet I sent it to was

1kgXpdiYKZq5bLEVUhABiHbu4nLsg7bCT

I spoke to bittylicious and did all the things they suggested - the cash (just my cash) is still in the blockchain but it never arrived at my own wallet - so the next sugestion was to speak directly to you

tx id was
329a685c425dee8a655d24f44aab47ed30ea4191c8de51ef1c36644e4ae43c5e

as I said the BTC are still on the blockchain it was  £106.25  and the BTC was  0.0036  none of these amounts show on my own wallet.  I would appreciate some help as  £106.25    is a lot of money at the moment in my world.

if you need any further information please dont hesitate to ask

Yours PM Lucas

PS this is the link to the bitty tx I made when it didnt arrive at my wallet = bitty say everything has been checked and it all worked as it should and dont know when I cant access the BTC

https://bittylicious.com/trade/BCY6UJ6VD

---

the wallet is on a smart phone [www.gnu.org/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin](http://www.gnu.org/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin)

Comment: One reason (normal self-custodial) wallets sometimes dont show money that has been received is that the wallet isn't fully synchronised. What exact software are you using as your wallet?

Comment: Your link www.gnu.org/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

the wallet is still on google store and these are the links given in the apps info and they seem to work ok for me - I backedup - deleted app = then re=installed app

Bitcoin Wallet is open source and free software. License: GPLv3
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html

Our source code is available at GitHub:
https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet

All translations are managed via Transifex:
https://www.transifex.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/